# Flat picker date showing in unexpected format

Tags: html, typescript, flatpickr, angular-slickgrid

Expected date format is "DD-MM-YYYY" but shown date format as "YYYY-MM-DD" in UI.

[Click here to show UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWvYX.jpg)

1. Before opening the date picker, date is shown in the expected format as "DD-MM-YYYY".
2. When the date picker is opened, the date format is changed in to "YYYY-MM-DD" format.
3. After closing date picker, it came back to the previous state (expected format as "DD-MM-YYYY").

How to show same date format in all the three states mentioned above ?

Answer (score 0):

`outputType` is what you need, read the [Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Editors#editor-output-type--save-output-type), if you want to change the date separator (`-`, `/`, `.`) then following this [dateSeparator - Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Formatters#common-formatter-options)

Comment: There is only predefined date types in outputType. I need to use my custom date type like 'DD-MM-YYYY' => 28-02-2001(IST date format), DD/MMM/YY => 28/JAN/98 , YYYY/MM/DD => 2013/07/14 etc....
etc...

Comment: Any update on this? @ghiscoding

Comment: all those types are supported already, just change the `dateSeparator`, I updated the answer to demo that. Apart from that the lib probably won't work with custom `FieldType`, the formatting of the date happens in this util function [mapFlatpickrDateFormatWithFieldType](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/master/packages/common/src/services/utilities.ts#L608)